# Using REST to update list items - cannot set fields to null/blank or overwrite the ModifiedBy field

Tags: 2013, rest, designer-workflow, sharepoint-designer, https

Using this resource: [REST services in SPD2013](https://blog.vgrem.com/2014/05/08/consuming-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-service-from-sharepoint-designer/), I was able to build a dictionary in order to update specific list items on demand.

However, I cannot seem to find an acceptable way to set date fields or user fields to null like you would do with JavaScript, etc. if you wanted to blank out a field using the REST API. Similarly, setting EditorId to [some ID here] doesn't seem to work. I'm using an app step to get around a user permission issue, but EditorId doesn't seem to be accepted as it would be in JavaScript. Are there any ways around either of these issues for SPD 2013?

edit: Setting user fields to "-1" seems to clear them out.

Answer (score 0):

You do overwrite the ModifiedBy value.

But what does SharePoint do **after** your update?

> SharePoint sets the ModifiedBy field to the User who did/triggered the update

Comment: Version history only shows one update to the ModifiedBy field - SharePoint App. Or is SharePoint overwriting the ModifiedBy even before an update is pushed? I just don't understand why we don't run into this issue with JSOM, CSOM, ajax, etc. :(